# SQL объединить запросы с противоположными условиями

Tags: mysql, запрос, объединение

Вопрос упростил насколько смог.

Первый запрос получает тему закреплённой статьи в разделе блога:

```
select part.pinned, blog.subject 
from part, blog 
where part.id = 5 and blog.id = part.pinned
```

Второй запрос получает остальные статьи с учётом пагинации и без закреплённой в разделе:

```
select blog.id, blog.subject 
from blog, part 
where blog.part = 5 and blog.id != part.pinned and blog.part = part.id 
order by blog.date_create desc 
limit 0, 10
```

Выходные данные из запросов одинаковые.

Вопрос: как объединить два запроса в один, чтобы первой строкой шла закреплённая статья?

Comment: `order by blog.id != part.pinned`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: сортировать по двум параметрам, перечисляем параметры через запятую

```
select blog.id, blog.subject, blog.date_create  
from blog, part  
where blog.part = 5  and blog.part = part.id  
order by blog.id != part.pinned  asc , blog.date_create desc 
limit 0, 10
```